# How to make Discord bot detect audio from user(s) in a voice chat?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to create a Discord bot, which uses Google Cloud Speech services API to allow the bot to be voice-controlled. (Goal is to help Discord community members with vision problems). However I ran into some issues, and surprisingly enough not with the API itself, but it seems that the Discord bot doesn't register the event when a user is speaking in the voice channel.

The following code makes the bot join the voice channel, in which the user is, upon using /activate slash command. The connection is established, but the bot seems not to be 'listening'. It's supposed to log any incoming voice activity from the user(s), but nothing seems to be detected.

This is the index.js:

```js
const path = require('node:path');
process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = path.join(__dirname, "omega-keyfile.json");

const fs = require('node:fs');
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials, Events, SlashCommandBuilder, Collection, VoiceChannel } = require('discord.js');
const { joinVoiceChannel, createAudioResource, createAudioPlayer, StreamType, AudioPlayerStatus } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const {token, clientId, clientKey, prefix} = require('./config.json');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { helpEmbed } = require('./Commands/general/help.js');
const createRoom = require('./commands/lfg/create-room');
const fetch = require('fetch-ponyfill')().fetch;
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
const { Transform } = require('stream');
const { log } = require('node:console');


const client = new Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    ], partials: [Partials.Channel]
});

client.commands = new Collection(); 

const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    } else {
        console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
    }
}

new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('ping')
    .setDescription('Replies with pong!');

new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('invite')
    .setDescription('Invites a user to a voice channel');

new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('help')
    .setDescription('Shows a list of commands');
new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('activate')
    .setDescription('Activates the Speech to Text feature');

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    const activityName = ["DO NOT USE, BOT IS IN DEVELOPMENT"];
    client.user.setPresence({ activities: [{ name: activityName[Math.floor(Math.random() * activityName.length)] }], status: 'online' , type: "WATCHING"});

    client.application.commands.create({
        name: 'ping',
        description: 'Replies with Pong!',
    });

    client.application.commands.create({
        name:'help',
        description: 'User Guide',
    });

    client.application.commands.create({
        name:'get-id',
        description: 'Retrieves YouTube Channel ID',
    });

    client.application.commands.create({
        name:'activate',
        description: 'Activates the Speech to Text feature',
    });
});


client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'Secret Pong!', ephemeral: true });
    }

    if (interaction.commandName === 'help') {
        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [helpEmbed] }); 
    }

    if (interaction.commandName === 'get-id') {
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'ID Retrieved.' });
    }

    if (interaction.commandName === 'create-room') {
        const { name, maxPlayers, game, numberOfPlayers } = interaction.options;
        createRoom(interaction, name, maxPlayers, game, numberOfPlayers);
        console.log(name, maxPlayers, game, numberOfPlayers);
        console.log('Room Created');
        await interaction.reply({
          content: `Room Created: ${name} ${maxPlayers} ${game} ${numberOfPlayers}`,
        });
      }
    console.log(interaction);
});


client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
  
    if (interaction.commandName === 'activate') {
        const voiceChannel = interaction.member.voice.channel;
        if (!voiceChannel) {
            return interaction.reply({
                content: "You need to be in a voice channel to use this command.",
                ephemeral: true,
            });
        }
  
        const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: voiceChannel.id,
            guildId: voiceChannel.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: voiceChannel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
        });

        console.log(connection.state); // Should log 'signalling' or 'ready'

        const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

        const request = {
            config: {
                encoding: 'LINEAR16',
                sampleRateHertz: 48000,
                languageCode: 'en-US',
            },
            interimResults: false,
        };

        const recognizeStream = client
            .streamingRecognize(request)
            .on('error', error => {
                console.error(`Recognize stream error: ${error}`);
            })
            .on('data', data => {
                console.log(`Recognize stream data: ${data}`);
                const transcription = data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript;
                console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
                interaction.channel.send(`Transcription: ${transcription}`); // delete this later, just for testing
                if (transcription.toLowerCase() === 'ping') {
                    interaction.channel.send('Pong!');
                }
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log('Recognize stream ended');
            });

        const convertToMono = new Transform({            
            transform: (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
                let monoChunk = new Int16Array(chunk.length / 4);
                for (let i = 0; i < monoChunk.length; i++) {
                    monoChunk[i] = chunk.readInt16LE(i * 4);
                }
                callback(null, Buffer.from(monoChunk.buffer));
            },
        });

        const receiver = connection.receiver;
  
        connection.on('speaking', async (user, speaking) => {
            console.log(`Speaking state change. User: ${user.username}, Speaking: ${speaking}`); //Testing purposes
            if (speaking.bitfield) {
                const audioStream = connection.receiver.subscribe(user).pipeline;
                audioStream.on('data', (chunk) => {                             // testing purposes, delete later?
                    console.log(`Received ${chunk.length} bytes of data.`);
                });
                audioStream.pipe(convertToMono).pipe(recognizeStream);
                console.log(`Sample rate: ${connection.receiver.ssrcToSpeakingData.get(user.id).sampleRate}`); // testing purposes

            }
        });
        return interaction.reply({
            content: 'Speech to Text activated. Start speaking to see the results.',
            ephemeral: true,
        });
    }
});


client.login(token);
```

Also, I know that having environmental variables hard-coded in my code is a bad practice but I don't intend to publish this bot anywhere. Furthermore, I'm still learning JavaScript and I'm using Google Cloud Services for the first time, so forgive me for any errors you might come across. I will appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

Comment: As of right now, I've found out that any feature that allows for the recording and storing of voice data without explicit user consent would be in violation of Discord's privacy policies. So I guess this project is a no go. Thanks for your help anyway!